# How do I list directory contents in ConEmu console?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, conemu

I recently installed ConEmu to replace the default CMD. The "ls" command to list current directory contents isnt working. How do I get back this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple suggestions:

- Use "[Dir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dir_(command))" instead.
- Make a batch file named `ls.bat`, which contains `@dir %1`, and put it in your [Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) someplace.

Comment: Or install this: http://utools.com/msls.asp

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get back this feature?

Back? You mean it was working on your PC before? That means it is working in ConEmu too!

ConEmu is **not** a shell but terminal only! Use your shell you was running before ConEmu to get "ls" back. Just set up it as startup command line ConEmu settings.

I can't imagine what shell you was using, must probably that was PowerShell or bash.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this, and the Marked answer is not I was looking for. While it's a great solution systemwide I prefer to do in ConEmu.
Basically this can be done by Aliases:

- Go ConEmu Settings
- Go to Environment
- Add "alias ls=dir"

https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsEnvironment.html

That's a handy feature especially if you have bunch of commands.